# Variable variables in PHP and URL functions

Tags: php, variables

Here's a piece of code:

```
$obj = new myClass();
$obj->{$_GET["func"]}($_GET["param"])
```

It works based on variable variables, but I don't really understand how.
As far as I know, variable variables are used for stuff like this:

```
require "dbsettings.php"
$member_id = $_GET['id'];
$db = new DBconnector();
$vars = array('username','passw','email','info','datejoined','dateofbirth');

foreach ($vars as $var) {
  $$var = $db->getUserInfo($member_id,$var);
}
echo $username;
echo $passw;
echo $email;
echo $info;
echo $datejoined;
echo $dateofbirth;
```

So, in the first piece of code, what's happening? Also, what function do the braces serve? What do they tell the compiler to think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$obj->{$_GET["func"]}($_GET["param"])
```

Simply calls the method whose name is stored in $_GET["func"], and pass as a parameter $_GET["param"].

The parentheses serve to disambiguate the method name (you also use parentheses in strings for similar purposes, e.g. `echo "calling {$_GET['func']}";`

See the [PHP manual page on variable variables](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more, e.g.

> In order to use variable variables
>   with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you
>   write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to
>   know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a
>   variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the
>   variable and then the `[1]` index from
>   that variable. The syntax for
>   resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}`
>   for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for
>   the second.

**A note on security**

As this is the accepted answer, I'm going to add that you shouldn't use user input so blindly, there may be methods on $obj which you wouldn't want be called.

You could, for example, check the method name against an array of allowed methods, e.g.

```
$method=$_GET["func"];
$ok=in_array($method, array('foo', 'bar', 'frobozz'));
```

Alternatively, you could only allow method names which follow a particular pattern, e.g. prefixed with 'ajax':

```
$method=$_GET["func"];
$ok=preg_match('/^ajax[A-Za-z]/', $method);
```

Or a variation on that idea, where the prefix is added to the passed method name so that only methods with that prefix can be called

```
$method='ajax'.preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $_GET["func"]);
```

There are other ways, but hopefully that illustrates a basic tenet: *assume your worst enemy constructed the `$_GET` array!*

Comment: I get it. So if my func paramter is "GetID" and param is 2, what I get it: $obj->GetID(2);

Comment: This is, of course, dangerous; in practice you'd never want to accept a function name from untrusted user input. But you're dealing with that, right?

Comment: The [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) function can be of use, too, especially if access to public members is the whitelist of valid functions to call. See as well: [print_r to get object methods in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290117/print-r-to-get-object-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

It's basically calling a funcion depending on parameters.

So, if you make a request like:

```
mypage.php?func=prop&param=value
```

What you'll end up getting this function call:

```
$obj->prop('value')
```

Braces serve to keep the array notation together and apply that ["func"] to the $_GET variable instead of $obj->$_GET (which could be a valid array). If you didn't use braces, what you'll be doing would be similar to:

```
($obj->$_GET)["func"](...)
```

In this case, note that you would be asking for the key "func" of array $obj->$_GET, instead of just $_GET.