# print_r to get object methods in PHP?

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm working with Views 2 in Drupal 6, and I am having difficulty finding documentation on the methods of the View object. Is there any PHP function like print_r that outputs methods as well as fields?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [get_class_methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php). If this is the case, [get_class_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) may also interest you.

Answer (score 11):

The [Reflection API](http://nz.php.net/oop5.reflection) might be of interest to you (if it's not overkill). Specifically:-

```
<?php
    Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass('View'));
?>
```

Check out the manual for more in-depth examples.

Comment: More flexible than get_class_methods because you can also get parameters and comments.

Comment: Also handy: `get_class($object);`
When you're dealing with a generated object from a generated class, you can pass this in to the ReflectionClass constructor.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Answer (score 3):

Besides the functions mentioned by Mathachew you can also take a look at [Reflection](http://php.net/reflection), especially the `ReflectionClass` class.

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('YourViewClass');
$class->getMethods();
$class->getProperties();
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this simple function which not only displays the methods of a given object, but also shows its properties, encapsulation and some other useful information like release notes if given.

```
function TO($object){ //Test Object
                if(!is_object($object)){
                    throw new Exception("This is not a Object"); 
                    return;
                }
                if(class_exists(get_class($object), true)) echo "<pre>CLASS NAME = ".get_class($object);
                $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
                echo "<br />";
                echo $reflection->getDocComment();

                echo "<br />";

                $metody = $reflection->getMethods();
                foreach($metody as $key => $value){
                    echo "<br />". $value;
                }

                echo "<br />";

                $vars = $reflection->getProperties();
                foreach($vars as $key => $value){
                    echo "<br />". $value;
                }
                echo "</pre>";
            }
```

To show you how it works I created some random example class. Lets create a class called Person and place some release notes just above the class declaration:

```
        /**
         * DocNotes -  This is description of this class if given else it will display false
         */
        class Person{
            private $name;
            private $dob;
            private $height;
            private $weight;
            private static $num;

            function __construct($dbo, $height, $weight, $name) {
                $this->dob = $dbo;
                $this->height = (integer)$height;
                $this->weight = (integer)$weight;
                $this->name = $name;
                self::$num++;

            }
            public function eat($var="", $sar=""){
                echo $var;
            }
            public function potrzeba($var =""){
                return $var;
            }
        }
```

Now lets create a instance of a Person and wrap it with our function.

```
    $Wictor = new Person("27.04.1987", 170, 70, "Wictor");
    TO($Wictor);
```

This will output information about the class name, parameters and methods, including encapsulation info and number and names of parameters for each method, method location and lines of code where it exists. See the output below:

```
CLASS NAME = Person
/**
             * DocNotes -  This is description of this class if given else it will display false
             */

Method [  public method __construct ] {
  @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\www\kurs_php_zaawansowany\index.php 75 - 82

  - Parameters [4] {
    Parameter #0 [  $dbo ]
    Parameter #1 [  $height ]
    Parameter #2 [  $weight ]
    Parameter #3 [  $name ]
  }
}

Method [  public method eat ] {
  @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\www\kurs_php_zaawansowany\index.php 83 - 85

  - Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [  $var = '' ]
    Parameter #1 [  $sar = '' ]
  }
}

Method [  public method potrzeba ] {
  @@ C:\xampp\htdocs\www\kurs_php_zaawansowany\index.php 86 - 88

  - Parameters [1] {
    Parameter #0 [  $var = '' ]
  }
}


Property [  private $name ]

Property [  private $dob ]

Property [  private $height ]

Property [  private $weight ]

Property [ private static $num ]
```

Hope you will find it useful. Regards.