# in php, how can I describe an object's properties and methods?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [print_r to get object methods in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290117/print-r-to-get-object-methods-in-php)

How can I show what all the objects' methods and properties are?

That is, including the property's values?

Comment: You mean [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)($yourObject) ?

Answer (score 5):

See [get_class_methods()](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) and [get_class_vars()](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php).

Also worth nothing that PHP's documentation is pretty good and generally a good place to ask first.

Edit: Of course, asking here seems to have its benefits as well. I never knew about the ReflectionClass Davide brought up :)

Answer (score 5):

To discover what the properties and the methods of an object are you can use [ReflectionClass](http://it.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

Comment: I think using Reflection to only get the class properties and methods is overkill.

Comment: It depends on how many details you need: to just get the names of properties and methods get_class_methods() and get_class_cars() are fine, but if more informations are needed, like method parameters or access modifiers, Reflection is the way to go, imo.

Comment: You likely meant `ReflectionObject`